# Shipment number XXX is currently being processed

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have the following scenario:

With a Z report I create a Shipment number (BAPI_SHIPMENT_CREATE). My report displays an ALV. If I double click on created shipment number, I go to VT03N. There I try to "Change" the shipment (Shipment-> Change). But the I get the error message that the shipment is locked by my user.

In this case I tried to unlock the shipment before calling VT03N with DEQUEUE_EVVTTKE. Now I have another problem: "The delivery number YYYY is locked by me". Delivery number linked to this shipment number. I tried analog with DEQUEUE_EVVBLKE, but the error message persists. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you commited your changes after creating a shipment with `BAPI_SHIPMENT_CREATE` and stepping into transaction `VT03N`?

Comment: Yes, I have ...

Answer (score 0):

I used FUNCTION 'LEINT_DELIVERY_UNLOCK' to unlock the delivery. It worked.

Comment: I think that forcing an unlock of the delivery instead of figuring out why the shipment bapi won't let go of the lock is going to cause you headaches once you get this into production.

Comment: I think you're right. But how to figure out this this bapi issue?
Or in the production this issue might  not appear?